# Force Touch Menu Action not firing

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I've added a Menu to my Storyboard but for some reason when I link up the IBActions and fire a deep press absolutely nothing is logged to the console

```
- (IBAction)doMenuItemAction 
{
 NSMutableArray *smallArray = [self.Array objectAtIndex:0];
 [self.dataArray addObject:smallArray];
 NSLog(@"%d", self.dataArray.count);
 [self sendDataArrayToTheWatch]; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have an `NSLog` or some similar in the `IBAction`?
Need some code, ideally a new project with minimum code to replicate the issue.

Comment: @4oby  this is my code  - (IBAction)doMenuItemAction {
    
    NSMutableArray *smallArray = [self.Array objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.dataArray addObject:smallArray];
    
    NSLog(@"%d", self.dataArray.count);
    
    [self sendDataArrayToTheWatch];
}

Comment: your array can be `self.dataArray == nil`, to ensure that the `IBAction` is called, add a breakpoint, or `NSLog(@"TheMenuItemActionHappened")`, one more thing, does the watch show the menu on force touch?

Comment: @4oby it isn't even logging nil

Comment: @4oby got it working! Was just a confusion between shallow press and deep press.

Answer (score 0):

ok here you go, a working example project

https://github.com/4oby/AppleWatchForceMenuExample